# How to get an image from gallery with a path to it at Android 10?

Tags: java, android, android-storage

My app gets an image path and stores it as a String in database. Then, in another activity, it gets an image from gallery with this path. This code works fine on emulator with 6 version of Android, but doesn't work on my phone with 10 version.

```
    public void displayBook(Book book) {
    dSdate.setText(book.getsDate());
    dFdate.setText(book.getfDate());
    dName.setText(book.getName());
    dAuthor.setText(book.getAuthor());
    dOpinion.setText(book.getOpinion());
    dQuote.setText(book.getQuote());


    if (!book.getCover().equals("")) {
        image = new File(book.getCover());
        if (image.exists()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    DisplayActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

}

  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            IVcover.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(image));
        }
 return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

I get path to an image with this method:

```
    private String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return "";
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "My app gets an image path" -- that does not sound promising. Could you expand your [mcve] to show how you are getting this "image path"?

Comment: @CommonsWare I added a method that gets path to an image.

Comment: Your `getRealPathFromUri()` will not work for most `Uri` values. It also will not work well on Android 10, as you will not have filesystem access to most files by default, regardless of what permissions you hold.